# How to select all faces of a Circle object prior to bpy.ops.uv.cube_project(cube_size=10)

Tags: python, mesh, faces, bmesh, select

```
#I have cup shaped object that starts with a circle that is extruded and scaled
# I need to select all faces in edit mode to UV unwrap faces(Right click)
# I cannot select all faces. Please help

# Does not work
so = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = so
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='FACE')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
bpy.ops.uv.cube_project(cube_size=10)



# Works only in VERT mode
mesh = so.data
bm=bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='VERT')
vtest = False  ##see if we can select side of active
for vert in bm.verts:
    vert.select = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first example isn't working because you are toggling the selection rather than setting it. change

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
```

to

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
```

for it to actually select all the faces.  Also, you don't need the second line, so your first example could be as simple as

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='FACE')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.uv.cube_project(cube_size=10)
```

If you want to use bmesh to select faces then you need to do something like this

```
object = bpy.context.object
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(object.data)
faces = bm.faces
bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()

for face in bm.faces:
    face.select = True

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(object.data)

bpy.ops.uv.cube_project(cube_size=10)
```

Note that the above code *assumes* that the selected object is a mesh object and is in edit mode.  You should add code to ensure that such things are so.

Comment: Your fix worked. Thanks a ton for the fast reply. Beginner's blues.